# Secondary screen shut off on "second screen only"

Tags: windows, laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I've got laptop + secondary extended screen lg 29', and I'm working on the secondary screen. It is good when I press fn + key to switch screen and "second screen only" and laptop screen is shutting down which is what i want to have after loading computer automatic.

I want to achive this because I don't wanna lose laptop screen life time.

Windows 8.1

Screen Connected HDMI

Thank you for help

Comment: Your question is not really clear.

Comment: Hmm sorry if it's not. I mean that I want after reboot system to get secondary screen as default. But when I restart it is as secondary but first (laptop screen) is not shut down but only dimm